# what is return data type of JSON.stringify() and how we can fetch data on server-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax

what is return data-type of JsonStringfy() if we pass an object and what data-type of parameter i should pass in my [WebMethod], so that it can fetched data returned from client-side page.

Both functions are listed.

### 1) Ajax function

```
var em = {};


    em.EnableSSL = enableSsl;
    em.Mode = emailMode;
    em.MailHost = smtpHost;
    em.MailPort = mailPort;
    em.MailFrom = mailFrom;
    em.MailTo = mailTo;
    em.MailCc = mailCc;
    em.MailBcc = mailBcc;
    em.ExceptionMailTo = exceptionMailTo;
    em.ExceptionMailCc = exceptionMailCc;
    em.ExceptionMailBcc = exceptionMailBcc;

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "PageName/MethodName",
        data: '{em : "' + JSON.stringify(em) + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
            console.log(obj);




        },
        error: function (errorData) {
            console.log(errorData.status);
        }
    });
```

### 2) Server-side method that execute on ajax call.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string MethodName(//Datatype? em)
    {
        var emailSettings = em;
        {

        }
        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonData = jsonSerializer.Serialize("Hi");
        return jsonData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We've had success setting the type to Dictionary.  So:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MethodName(Dictionary<string, object> em)
```

My understanding is that MS will use the type you choose to do the actual deserialization, so other types might work as well, but this seems like the best choice.